# What should be done when getting resyncApplyDifferences error in OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm getting the following error when calling `/delta`:

> resyncApplyDifferences: Resync required. Replace any local items with the server's version (including deletes) if you're sure that the service was up to date with your local changes when you last sync'd. Upload any local changes that the server doesn't know about.

What it's asking is for seems quite extreme, do I need to wipe out all the items I have and replace them with the server version? I know that the current sync state is fine so is there any way to bypass this error?

Also what's triggering this message? Is there any way to avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error content here sounds a bit more severe that it really is. Basically it's saying there is an issue with the delta token and the service can no longer determine the changes to the Drive since your last poll.

If you're 100% sure there are no changes, you can simply reset by requesting a `/delta` without a token and starting over. If you're not 100% sure, you can compare that fresh `/delta` with your local files and re-apply any changes required (upload local files missing from the drive, delete files removed from the drive, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that makes sense. Any idea what can cause the delta token to become invalid? Is that because they expire?

Comment: There isn't really much you can do to avoid it - there are some scenarios that will cause the service to not adequately track the status of an item, which necessitates this kind of resync. It will happen more often when running delta on a shared folder in OneDrive Consumer - is that where you're seeing it?

Comment: Ok I see, thank you. Resyncing is quite a heavy operation in my scenario as I have potentially thousands of files to recheck, but it can be done. I'm not using OneDrive Consumer, I'm doing my tests on a regular free account and it seems to happen mostly on clients that I didn't sync for a long time.

Comment: @Brad, by the way, is it possible to generate this error (by manually changing the token for example)? While doing tests I've lost this token that was giving me this sync error and now I cannot recreate the conditions to test. I'm interested in particular in the `Location` header mentioned in the doc. Is it the same as `/delta` with no arguments or is there something more to it?